# How to append another argument in the __init__() of subclass?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So basically I have a parent class with some arguments in the **init**(), now I want to define a subclass, I want to redefine the **init**() in the subclass just append a new argument in it. Is there any convenient way to complete this?

Here is my code:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

    def display_car(self):
        #print "This is a "+self.color+" "+self.model+" with "+str(self.mpg)+" MPG."
        print self.condition

    def drive_car(self):
        self.condition = "used"

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg,battery_type):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg
        self.battery_type = battery_type

my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)
my_car = ElectricCar("Fuck me","Gold",998,"molten salt")


print my_car.condition
my_car.drive_car()
print my_car.condition
```

The new argument is `battery_type`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `super()` to access the parent class' `__init__()` and let parent init its attributes . Example -

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg,battery_type):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```